"Text Input in Streamlit Removes Entered Text Upon Hitting Enter Key: How to Fix?"
the input stored in user_question i need when press enter the txt in textbox getting clear and the output displing what can i did i tried js and streamlit function but when enter input and press send btn or press enter no output displaying 

enter image description here
here is an example of an image entered word pressed, and enter
textbox didnot not get clear

It's seems, you must to do a function for clear it
Like that:
import streamlit as st

def clear_text():
    st.session_state["text"] = ""

input = st.text_input("text", key="text")    
st.button("clear text input", on_click=clear_text)
st.write(input)

As is explain here: streamlit issue

you can to use the

chat_input

(doc)
this component do exactly what you want to do
